# Office.onReady() thinks it's running in Excel when our code executes outside of the OWA

Tags: office-js, office-addins

We recently updated our OWA add-in to use the new `Office.onReady()` promise for making sure that OfficeJs is ready.
This also fixes IE11 from freezing over  while trying to load the OfficeJs library on a slow network connection.

This is how that looks like:

```
if (Office !== undefined) {
  Office.onReady().then((info: { host: Office.HostType, platform: Office.PlatformType }) => {
    console.log(`starting add-in for environment: ${environment.OWA_URL} on host: ${info.host}, platform: ${info.platform}`);
    bootStrapAngular();
  });
} else {
  this.utilService.logMessage(LogLevel.DEBUG, 'Bootstrapping Angular, without OfficeJS');
  // FIXME lazy load an OfficeJS mock??
  bootStrapAngular();
}
```

We find that - even though we should mock Office - locally, OfficeJs seems to think that it is running in `Excel` (it's not), on `PC` (it's not):

inside OWA, opening the right pane:

`starting ... on host: Outlook, platform: OfficeOnline`

outside OWA, `https://localhost:port`:

`starting ... on host: Excel, platform: PC`

We can work around this by requiring that the host is `Outlook` and the platform is `OfficeOnline`, but this seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its a known issue and the team is working on a fix.